# product which has sold the most inner join

Tags: sql, inner-join

I need to show the most popular selling item from the products table joining the sales table.
I need to display the  most popular selling items.

Here's the code I've tried :

```
SELECT products.prod_id, products.prod_name, sales.quantity, 
FROM products
INNER JOIN sales ON products.prod_id = sales.prod_id
```

Here are pics products and sales 
products
[image: products]
sales
[image: sales]

Comment: 3 Answers, 3 syntax errors... Does your own code run at all?

Comment: That would be helpful to mention in your question. It does sounds like your tables have different names, could you check?

Comment: Nope its just products and sales..

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Also, which flavour of sql do you use (sql server, mysql, oracle etc.)?

Comment: Just noticed you also have a ',' too many, behind sales.quantity. Does it run if you remove it?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT products.prod_id, products.prod_name, sum(sales.quantity) as sales_total 
FROM products
INNER JOIN sales ON products.prod_id = sales.prod_id
GROUP BY products.prod_id, products.prod_name
```

Comment: I see I had kept erroneus , at the end of select list. Thanks to RADAR of fixing it; now syntax errors should be gone?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT products.prod_id, products.prod_name, SUM(sales.quantity) as sales_total, 
FROM products
INNER JOIN sales ON products.prod_id = sales.prod_id
GROUP BY products.prod_id, products.prod_name
ORDER BY sales_total DESC
```

Comment: In the words of Obi Wan - "This is the query you are looking for"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT products.prod_id, products.prod_name, SUM(sales.quantity), 
FROM products
INNER JOIN sales ON products.prod_id = sales.prod_id
GROUP BY prod_id
ORDER BY 3 DESC
LIMIT 25
```

You will want an index such as (prod_id, quantity) on sales.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.prod_id, p.prod_name, b.Qty  
FROM (  
    SELECT a.prod_id, a.Qty, MAX(a.Qty) OVER () AS MaxQty  
    FROM (  
        SELECT s.prod_id, SUM(s.quantity) AS Qty  
        FROM sales s   
        GROUP BY s.prod_id ) a ) b  
INNER JOIN Products p ON p.prod_id = b.prod_id  
WHERE b.Qty = b.MaxQty
```

Comment: The query makes use of nested select statements. The inner most (a) gets the quantity total by product. The Select staring on 3rd line uses an analytics function 'MAX(..) OVER ()' to get the greatest quantity total over the whole set. And the outer select matches greatest quantity total with product quantity totals - giving us the product we want. Then of course join to get product name. This was trialled in SQL Server using tables with different names (I think from Northwind sample db), then I replaced table and column names to conform with question. Could also achieve this using a WITH